# Why custom post redirecting to index page?

Tags: custom-post-types, single

i am new learner and trying to build a `wordpress theme`i need your help in theme building ,my problem is that, i created a custom post type name is `events`
and also created a `single-events.php` template inside my theme so that only events post can be display but when i clicked on permalink of it's post then it does not redirect to `single-events.php`, it redirect to index page ,can please anybody give me solution with example.

/custom post code is/

```
add_action ('init', 'register_events_posttype');
function register_events_posttype(){
   $labels = array();

    $args = array(
        'label' => 'events',
        'labels' => $labels,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events'),
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'menu_position' => 2,
        'capability_type'=>'post',
        'public' => true,
       'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'excerpt','custom-fields','thumbnail', 'archives',),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events','with_front' => false)
    );
    register_post_type('events', $args);
}
```

/and `single-events.php` code is/

```
<?php

get_header();
?>

events post
<?php echo get_the_title();?>
<?php
 get_footer();
 ?>
```

can you please solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to remove following line from last line

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events','with_front' => false)
```

And Visit the permalinks page at admin side (which will flush it) and save/check again. WordPress probably just needs to be nudged to recognize your addition to the hierarchy.

Comment: i just removed this line whoever it happening same as i told..

Comment: have you any suggestion about it for solution  or i need any hook in my theme?

Comment: Can u please tell me how's your single post URL ?